# Which handset or mobile should be opted for testing the Windows Phone 7 application?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I m building an application for WP7. So till now i was working on emulator but now i have to test the application on device.
Can anyone tell me which company's mobile (HTC and Nokia) is good for it do specify the model no also. As i come to know that HTC is switching to Android so i have to emphasize on long run also.
One thing more i require to know how to deploy an application on device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your program graphically intensive, or does it use features that are only found on specific phones?  If not, I would buy the slowest device you wish to be able to support.  In that way, it'll run superbly on higher-powered phones.

Having said that, the **Dell Venue Pro** and **HTC HD7** are currently being updated to the "NoDo" update (which brings in copy and paste) - so if you want to be able to develop against the latest and greatest, it would seem sensible to buy one of these.

Comment: no my application doesn't uses any specific features but i will need different font support in future also i m embedding some text files to my application. Also it should support sending sms through my application.

Comment: Have added some information that may help you decide.  To be honest, it sounds like you're just using plain OS features, which should work on any device.

Comment: thanks for reply but is it gud to opt HTC i think they are switching to Android. Wat abt Nokia

Comment: HTC are committed to both platforms.  If they weren't committed, they wouldn't be amongst the first to support the latest version of the OS.

Answer (score 2):

If you can only test on one device, get the slowest device, with the least RAM and the smallest screen you can.

This applies for all situations where you need to test something on a mobile where the same code will be used on different powered and sized devices.

If possible test on multipel devices. If you know someone with a different make/model ask to borrow theirs.

One of the current advantages to developing for Windows Phone 7 is that the same code SHOULD run on all WP7 devices. There have been a couple of exceptions reported but they are a very tiny minority or cases.

Comment: can u tell me any remote testing for application links where i can push my application for testing. I want to test my windows phone 7 application on several phones.